# Hide folder in Brackets

Tags: editor, adobe-brackets

I have a `node_modules` folder in my Brackets project folder. I don't want Brackets to display that folder, search it, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There’s an extension created by Glenn Ruehle, who is one of the developers at Adobe, that does exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/gruehle/exclude-folders

**Note**: This extension is not available in the Extension Manager. You’ll have to manually install it by clicking on ‘install from URL’ and paste the URL of the GitHub Repository.